# Firebase: how to get getAdditionalUserInfo in onCreate Firebase Cloud function

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get some additional data from a SAML login provider. I can see this data in the client but I fail to see how to get this in the back end (firebase functions).

I'm using these in the FE

```
"firebase": "^9.8.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
```

And this in the BE

```
"firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.21.2",
```

This is the data and how I get it in the client:

```
async myproviderSignIn() {
  const provider = new SAMLAuthProvider('saml.myprovider');
  const auth = getAuth();

  const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  const credential = SAMLAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(userCredential);

  if (!environment.production) {
    console.log('User:', userCredential, credential);
    console.log(
      'getAdditionalUserInfo:',
      getAdditionalUserInfo(userCredential)
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I'm after and logged by getAdditionalUserInfo in the client:

```
{
    "isNewUser": false,
    "providerId": "saml.myprovider",
    "profile": {
        "urn:schac:attribute-def:schacPersonalUniqueCode": "urn:schac:personalUniqueCode:nl:local:diy.myproviderconext.nl:studentid:123456",
        "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.25178.1.2.9": "diy.myproviderconext.nl",
        "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.25178.1.2.14": "urn:schac:personalUniqueCode:nl:local:diy.myproviderconext.nl:studentid:123456",
        "urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3": "student1@diy.myproviderconext.nl",
        "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1": [
            "student",
            "employee",
            "staff",
            "member"
        ],
        "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonAffiliation": [
            "student",
            "employee",
            "staff",
            "member"
        ],
        "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:sn": "One",
        "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:givenName": "Student",
        "urn:oid:2.5.4.42": "Student",
        "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail": "student1@diy.myproviderconext.nl",
        "urn:oid:2.5.4.4": "One",
        "urn:mace:terena.org:attribute-def:schacHomeOrganization": "diy.myproviderconext.nl"
    }
}
```

Finally this is my BE on user create trigger. It creates a DB record of the user when a new user is created in Firebase auth. I'd wish to map some of the properties shown above here to the user record in the DB.

```
export const onCreate = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate((user: UserRecord, context: EventContext) => {
    const timestamp = serverTimestamp();

    const dbUser: DbUser = {
      uid: user.uid,
      name: user.displayName || '',
      firstName: user.displayName || '',
      lastName: '',
      email: user.email,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      createdDate: timestamp,
      lastSeen: timestamp,
      providerData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.providerData)),
      userDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
      contextDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)),
    };

    // Get additional user data from the UserCredential
    // const additionalUserInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(user); ???

    const result = getFirestore()
      .collection(constants.dbCollections.users)
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set(dbUser);

    return result;
  });
```

**How do I access these additional properties in my cloud function without relying on the client?**

Comment: can you clarify that, additional means which data you want to show

Comment: I would probably store the data temporarily in firestore and have the trigger retrieve it when its triggered, not ideal though.

Comment: @omeanwell the point is to store it in Firestore, without relying on the client.

Comment: I dont think what you're asking is clear, or I think you have misunderstood my comment

Comment: @omeanwell I do not understand your comment. I'm trying to get the properties from the SAML provider in my BE in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you try to solve is something explained in here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#node.js

some of the data you described below is stored within the auth.user

```
const dbUser: DbUser = {
  uid: user.uid,
  name: user.displayName || '',
  firstName: user.displayName || '',
  lastName: '',
  email: user.email,
  photoURL: user.photoURL,
  emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
  createdDate: timestamp,<-----------------------------------------------here
  lastSeen: timestamp,<--------------------------------------------------and here
  providerData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.providerData)),
  userDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
  contextDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)),
};
```

but the data i marked as "here" needs to be created via "custom user claims" but its under the FireBaseAnalytics tab neither auth. nor firestore if you insist to retrive this data from Firebase.

```
But for this data :

  providerData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user.providerData)),
  userDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)),
  contextDump: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)),
```

you should use FireStore or FirebaseRealTimeDatabase i repeat if you insist of getting those data from FireBase because of the 1000byte policy of Custom Claims.

i hope i do understand your question well. But im sure if you add those properties with this

```
// Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.

getAuth()
  .setCustomUserClaims(uid, { admin: true })
  .then(() => {
    // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
    // next time a new one is issued.
  });
```

you can retrive it with .auth token

Comment: I know about custom claims, the problem is I don't know how to access the attributes from my saml provider in the back end.

Comment: Could you pls describe “how  you get The auth Tokens to back end. 

   İ asker one of my friends who just leave saml and moved to oidc. We may çöme out with a solution

Comment: Not a bad idea, I will look into OIDC and see if it is possible that way.